# Json erroring when going from controller to view

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

something is getting choked up when my data object gets back to my page.  It always goes to my 'error' function instead of my 'success' function.  Here is my current jquery function.  What I'm trying to do is populate a product on my page by inputting a UPC, and onblur fills in the corperateitemcode.  The data is populating in the controller but it errors on the page.  What makes this tricky for me is the page can have multiple products so I can't reference it by id.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
 function FillProductbyupc(elem) {
        var $elem = $(elem),
            upcCode = $elem.data('upc');

        $.ajax({
            url: '/Case/GetData/',
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "JSON",
            data: "upc=" + upcCode,
            success: function (data) {
                $(".corpitemcode").append(
                $elem.find('.corpitemcode').val(data.CorpItemCode));
                $(".itemdesc").append(
                 $elem.find('.itemdesc').val(data.ItemDsc));
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("UPC does not exist");
            }
        });
    }
    $(function () {

        $('.products').on('blur', '[data-upc]', function (e) {
            FillProductbyupc(this);
        });
    });
```

Heres my product

```
<div class="product">

    <p>
        <label>Product</label>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UPC, null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.UPC), data_upc = "5440001504" })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.PLU, null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.PLU) })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.CorpItemCode, null, new { @class = "form-control corpitemcode", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.CorpItemCode) })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.ItemDsc, null, new { @class = "form-control itemdesc", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.ItemDsc) })
        @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.LaneNumber, null, new { @class = "form-control", placeholder = Html.DisplayNameFor(x => x.LaneNumber) })

        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.DeleteProduct, new { @class = "mark-for-delete" })
        @Html.RemoveLink("Remove", "div.product", "input.mark-for-delete")





    </p>
</div>
```

My Controller

```
 public JsonResult GetData(string upc, decimal? corpitemcode)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(upc))
        {
          upc = upc.Replace("-", "");
        }

        CICS data = new CICS();
        data = CICSManager.GetbyUPCorCorp(upc, corpitemcode);

        return Json(data, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Comment: What's the error? Use your browsers dev tools, or include the error parameters in your callback.

Comment: @Brandon I don't get an actual error, it just doesn't populate the textboxes.  I see in the controller that the data is there in the data object.  But when I debug the javascript in FF when it hits the success function it doesn't make it to   '$(".corpitemcode").append(', it just goes straight to the error function.

Comment: Maybe your controller returning some http error code?

Comment: Can anyone show me what I need to toss in the code to see the error?